# SQL help wanted with distinct and group by

Tags: sql

I have a table with two important for me fields: id, dob. Need to count all id-s for which there are more than one dob exist in the table. Can't figure out what combination of groupby's and distinct to use.

Sample data:

```
id, dob
1, 01011980
1, 01031980
2, 11051950
2, 11051950
3, 02131976
4, 06071980
4, 06011980
4, 06011974
```

Real table has let's say a billion records.

Expected output for the data above should be: 2
That's for id-s 1 and 4, but I don't care about the list of those id-s.
On the other thought: another query with a list of id-s and counts for different dob-s might eventually become helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct id
from t
group by id, dob
having count(*) > 1
```

It will find those ids which have more than one row with same id and dob.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/VUP25999)

Comment: Unclear how this is the accepted answer given OP's comment of "Expected output for the data above should be: 2 That's for id-s 1 and 4, but I don't care about the list of those id-s. " and the actual output is a list of ids!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      COUNT(*)
FROM        table
GROUP BY    id, dob
HAVING      COUNT(dob) > 1
```

Comment: If there are more than one record with exactly the same id and dob, it shouldn't count as more than one. Only different dob-s for one id must be accounted. I.e., id=2 although has two records, both are with the same dob, => doesn't count.